# Make a slider for hourly weather forecast

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I am trying to make a weppage for hourly weather forecast. I have extracted data from an api and stored it in an array. 
I want to display that data in a way that it shows 10 hours of forecast,with 5 entries being actively shown.I want to create a slider like this:

http://www.accuweather.com/en/au/melbourne/26216/hourly-weather-forecast/26216

I have stored the data in a table and now need to make it slide or make it in form of carousel.
i have searched on internet,but most of them are for images or are either plugins.

Can somene please help me to understand how to create this effect. I dont wana use plugin.

Comment: use mostly CSS, nth-child selectors to show/hide certain cells. then put those rules behind a table class(g1, g2, g3). then, you can change the table class to swap out visible cells. `table.g1 td:nth-child(1)... { display: table-cell }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An incredibly simple approach would be to use JQuery Show and Hide.By default, you show the first view.On clicking the next button, you hide that view, and show another view.So on and so forth.

This is slightly crude, but does the job. Additionally, you cause use animations to transition them in and out.